# How I Can deploy a SpringBoot Application in WildFly?

Tags: java, spring-boot, wildfly, web-deployment

I have a very simple CRUD in Java with SpringBoot, and locally it runs perfectly, but I need to upload the .war to a WildFly server. When I do this, it displays correctly, but when I try to consume a service from postman, or enter the context-root, I get "Forbbiden". What configuration should I do, or how can I call the URL?

REST CONTROLLER:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/ex-excepciones")
public class ExExcepcionesController {

    private final ExExcepcionesService exExcepcionesService;

    public ExExcepcionesController(ExExcepcionesService exExcepcionesService) {
        this.exExcepcionesService = exExcepcionesService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<ExExcepcionesDto> findAll() {
        return exExcepcionesService.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<ExExcepcionesDto> findById(@PathVariable long id) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exExcepcionesService.findById(id), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PostMapping
    ResponseEntity<ExExcepcionesDto> create(@RequestBody ExExcepcionesRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exExcepcionesService.save(request), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @PatchMapping("/{id}")
    ResponseEntity<ExExcepcionesDto> update(@PathVariable Long id ,@RequestBody ExExcepcionesRequest request) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(exExcepcionesService.update(id,request), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Este es el Application:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SdmExcepcionesDeiApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {


    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurer() {
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH", "OPTIONS");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SdmExcepcionesDeiApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.10</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.sdm.excepciones.dei</groupId>
    <artifactId>SDM</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>SDM</name>
    <description>SDM</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.22</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>SDM</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.22</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>1.4.2.Final</version>
                        </path>

                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Entering the context-root of the wildfly throws this:

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZTSn.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwkJ5.png

and When trying to build the URL and consume the rest api:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/SDM/v1/ex-excepciones/
```

For localhost, it's the same.

```
http://localhost:8080/SDM/v1/ex-excepciones/
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mde4Z.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBZ18.png

Many thanks to anyone who can help me with this.

Comment: Your `configure` method on `SdmExcepcionesDeiApplication` may not be right. To match the `main` method, `SdmExcepcionesDeiApplication.class` should be used as the source.

Comment: Even so, changing by sdmexceptionsdeiplicione.class, follow the equal error